# How to get permissions for r_1st_connections

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linkedin-api

Is there a way to request permissions for r_1st_connections, we have a complete feature depending on this and given that Linkedin is taking it down we are in a big problem here, thanks in advance.

PS. we already have access for V2 but still getting this error message

`Not enough permissions to access: GET-viewer /connections`

I've already google it and no answers

Answer (score 2):

No. This permission is not available.